Is there an intuitive explanation for the properties of Pascal's triangle?
Pascal's triangle has two properties which are very interesting, but for which I have no "intuitive" explanation. If we list out Pascal's triangle by computing "n choose k" for each horizontal position, we find that...


Each element of Pascal's triangle is the sum of the two numbers above it

Each row sums to 2^n (where the first row is considered the 0th row)


I can blast out some algebra and prove both of these properties, but I'm looking for an intuitive explanation for why these are true. Is there a way to understand these two properties from the combinatoric interpretation of the triangle?

See Chapter 3 in Mathematics of Choice by Ivan Niven (1965).

I'm usually quick to say "this is about math rather than math education", but in this case I'm inclined to disagree with the close votes. I think various intuitive explanations for the properties of Pascal's triangle are extremely useful in math education.

I don't think there is a simple "intuitive" explanation if you mean "can be explained in a few lines and understood without much effort." However the J.R. answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453843/why-does-pascals-triangle-give-the-binomial-coefficients is a good attempt to link the topics.

Can you Post the students' age?, please? Else, isn't it balls? What would be wrong with billiard balls, ranged in rows as if they were racked up on a green baize table?
I suggest all the Answers here bar Dominique's are far beyond the level of any student struggling to understand Pascal's triangle.
I further suggest it matters a great deal whether we're trying to find an 'intuitive explanation' for how the triangle expands from row to row, or to devise a formula predicting the contents of a given, lower row.
Isn't it clear, no 'special' properties attach to the triangle?

How about the fact that $(x+y)^n=(x+y)\cdot (x+y)^{n-1}$, and then equating coefficients? This proves that ${n\choose k}={n-1\choose k-1}+{n-1\choose k}$.
... and... since $(1+1)^n=2^n$, the other assertions follow similarly.

this is very nice.

For #1 -- the bottom entry is the number of ways to choose $k$ objects from $n$. We can do this by specifying a particular object $x$. Then, how many ways can we:

intentionally select $x$? ${n - 1 \choose k-1}$, since we have already picked 1 of the $k$ desired objects and need to select $k-1$ from the remaining $n-1$.
intentionally not select $x$? ${n-1 \choose k}$ since we have to select the $k$ objects from the remaining $n-1$ choices.

Each selection of $k$ from $n$ either includes $x$ or it does not, so this exhausts all possibilities.
For #2 -- The sum of a row is the number of ways to select 0 objects from $n$, or 1 object, or 2 object or ..., or $n-1$, or $n$. This exhausts all possible subsets of the $n$ objects and we know that there are $2^n$ subsets.
(To see that there are $2^n$, for each of the $n$ objects, we have an independent binary choice: (0) do not include or (1) do include. Each $n$ length sequence of $0$s and $1$s gives a unique subset and there are $2^n$ sequences.)

For me these are the "canonical" explanations.

When I was $14$ years old, I invented Pascal's triangle myself: I was obsessed with powers (of $2$, $3$, $5$ and other numbers), and I had observed that there was a simple way to calculate the powers of $11$: every next power consisted of the sum of subsequent digits (just adding $1$ at the beginning and at the end):

$11$ : that's the start.
$121$ : the $2$ is the sum of both ones of $11$.
$1331$ : the first $3$ equals the sum of the first two digits of $121$, the second $3$ equals the sum of the last two digits of $121$.
$14641$ : $4=1+3$, $6=3+3$, $4=3+1$
$161051$ : oops!

By playing around, I discovered that the fifth power of $11$ should consist of $1$, $5$, $10$, $10$, $5$ and $1$, and indeed: perform the following sum:
000001
00005
0010
010
05
1

=> You end up with $161051$.
By playing around further, I also discovered that $1+1=2$, $1+2+1=4$, $1+3+3+1=8$, $1+4+6+4+1=16$, $1+5+10+10+5+1=32$, revealing an amazing link between the powers of $11$ and the ones of $2$, and I was off on a marvellous adventure in the wonders of number theory :-)

For the first fact:
Note that $\binom{n}{k}$ is exactly the number of ways to reach the entry when starting at the top and being allowed to fork either left or right at each step. Why? We have to move down $n$ times, and at each fork we have a choice of forking left or right. To reach the $k$-th entry on the $n$-th level we must go right exactly $k$ times. And we can choose freely at which level we do so. That is, we choose $k$ levels from $n$ where we go right. That's exactly $\binom{n}{k}$.
But we're not done. We need to see why each entry is the sum of the ones above it. Well, from the level above, the only ways to reach an entry are via the entries diagonally above the target entry. So to get all ways of reaching the target, we have to add all the ways of reaching the previous entries.
The second fact:
How many ways are there to reach an arbitrary entry on the $n$-th level? We can choose any combination of left and right forkings. That is, at each of the $n$ steps we have $2$ free choices. Which leads to $2^n$ combinations. And the sum of ways of reaching each individual entry is of course the number of ways of reaching any entry, which we argued is $2^n$.
Consequences:
By the way, this is the reason why the chance to end up in the $k$-th bin of an $n$ layers deep Galton board is $\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n}$. The same one would get by applying the formula for the binomial distribution.
